# Why I can't use exact P if P is a Prop?

Tags: coq

I am trying to prove contraposition. And my proof is like the following. It doesn't work.

```
Theorem contrapositive : forall (P Q : Prop),
  (P -> Q) -> (~Q -> ~P).
Proof.
  intros.
  destruct H0.
  apply H.
  Fail exact P. Abort.
```

My question is, after `apply H`, I get the following goal

```
1 goal
P, Q : Prop
H : P -> Q
______________________________________(1/1)
P
```

So, IMO, we have to prove `P`, and we have a `P` in our hypothesis. So why can't we just use `exact P`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have `P : Prop` in your assumptions is not the same as having a `p : P` in your assumptions.

If the goal is to prove `P`, `exact x` must be used with `x` as a term of type `P`, i.e, a proof of `P`. `P` is not a proof of `P`.

- `P : Prop` means "let `P` be an arbitrary proposition". It could be true, it could be false.
- `p : P` means "let `p` be a proof of `P`". That's what means that `P` is true.

Comment: Just a comment on this proof.  After "intros. destruct H0." your proof is in a dead-end, but the initial statement was provable.   You should try inserting an extra "intros H1." before the `destruct H0.` step and see what happens.  In this case, it is important to remember that we wanted to prove the negation of `P`.  The premature use of `destruct H0` forgets this information, which is crucial for the rest of the proof.